# What is the Polymer 3 way of using behaivors?

Tags: polymer, polymer-3.x

What's the proper way of using iron-overlay-behavior in Polymer 3. Shouldn't that be as simple as extending the class? But I ain't sure because my component already extends PolymerElement.

Any simple example should help.

Answer (score 5):

Have you looked at the [`Polymer.mixinBehaviors()`](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade#mixins) helper function? Behaviors are superseded by mixins as of Polymer 2, and as far as I can tell the version 3 does not bring any changes in that regard.

Here is how you would use `iron-overlay-behavior` in a Polymer 3 element:

```
import {PolymerElement} from '@polymer/polymer';
import {IronOverlayBehavior} from '@polymer/iron-overlay-behavior';
import {mixinBehaviors} from '@polymer/polymer/lib/legacy/class.js';

class MyOverlay extends
  mixinBehaviors([IronOverlayBehavior], PolymerElement) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: But it's bringing in legacy/class.js which is backward compatibility layer.

Comment: Indeed so. It's because `iron-overlay-behavior` has never been upgraded from Polymer 1.x. If you want to use it, you will have to use the compatibility layer.

Comment: Absolutely right, obviously the iron- and paper-behaviors are only available by the compatibilty layer at the moment. But if you create your own behaviors you can use the newer mixins ([docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/custom-elements#defining-mixins)) and just extend them in your Element: `class MyElement extends MyBehavior(PolymerElement) `

Answer (score 3):

```
import {mixinBehaviors} from '@polymer/polymer/lib/legacy/class.js';

class MyClass extends mixinBehaviors([MyBehavior], PolymerElement) { ... }
```

*from https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements#using-legacy-behaviors-with-class-style-elements*